# Mongodb group then count number of instances separately

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have some data in my collection similar to this,

```
  {name: one, Status: Unauthorised},
  {name: two, Status: Retired},
  {name: three, Status: Authorised},
  {name: two, Status: Unauthorised},
  {name: two, Status: Unauthorised},
  {name: two, Status: Retired},
  {name: three, Status: Unauthorised},
  {name: three, Status: Unauthorised},
  {name: one, Status: Retired},
```

how do i do an aggregation to get where i can get the count of how many unauthorized and Retired fields?

I want the output to look like this.

```
{name: one, Retired: 1, Unauthorised: 1,}
{name: two, Retired: 2, Unauthorised: 2,}
{name: three, Retired: 0, Unauthorised: 2,}
```

my code currently looks like this however this brings back a separate record for the two Status I want

```
    {$match: {Status: {$in:["Un-authorised", "Retired"]}}},
    {$group: {_id : {Status:'$Status', machineid:'$name'}, Unauthorised:{$sum :1}}},
    {$sort:{Unauthorised:-1}},
    {$project : {Status: '$_id.Status', machineid:'$_id.name', Unauthorised : '$Unauthorised', _id : 0}},
```

this the output equivalent

```
{name: one, Retired: 1,}
{name: one, Unauthorised: 1,}
{name: two, Retired: 2}
{name: two, Unauthorised: 2,}
{name: three, Retired: 0 }
{name: three, , Unauthorised: 2}
```

Comment: what have you tried? you can use $group by name and status.

Comment: @turivishal Hi please see my eddit for my current code and what it outputs

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code for next time. Also try this: [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UgOHL4hdqcn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try,

- `$match` your condition
- `$group` by `name` and `status` and get the sum of total status
- `$group` by `name` only and push status in k and value in v
- `$replaceWith` to replace root object, convert status (k,v) array to object using `$arrayToObject` and merge with name using `$mergeObjects`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      Status: { $in: ["Unauthorised", "Retired"] }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        name: "$name",
        Status: "$Status"
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.name",
      status: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.Status",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $mergeObjects: [
        { name: "$_id" },
        { $arrayToObject: "$status" }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_TZhYBE91rC)

---

Second option, for fix status condition in `$group`,

- `$group` by name
- create one field `Retired` for sum using `$cond` if its match then add one otherwise zero
- create one field `Unauthorised` for sum using `$cond` if its match then add one otherwise zero

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HGmGdFTgnir)

Comment: Thank you this works great the only issue is if an record does not have any retired or Unauthorised it just leaves it blank. But i can work that out myself

Comment: look at the second example, if statuses are fixed then you can use that.

Comment: Thank you that work perfectly real help didn't know you could do if statements in mongodb